# SQL Server - Date Add - Include specific time

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, dateadd

I need to pull in the last 48 hours of data, however I only need 24 hours. The reason why I am pulling in more data than necessary is because I do not know what time this script is going to run and the `[data].[table]` source might not have a full 24 hours. I need a full days data between these two specific times `00:00:00` and `23:59:59`.

For example: If today is `2022-04-25`, then I want to bring in data between `2022-04-24 00:00:00` `2022-04-24 23:59:59`.

```
SELECT [ID],[Timestamp],[Value]
FROM [data].[table]  
Where [Timestamp] >= DateAdd(day, -2, getdate())
```

Comment: Just use traditional date ranges: `TimeStamp >= '20220424' and TimeStamp < '20220425'` Getting yesterday's date (and today's) is simple with `DATEADD` and if you don't want a time portion then `CONVERT` a `date`.

Comment: Side note: `timestamp` is a poor choice of a column name in SQL Server; `timestamp` is a *deprecated* synonym of `rowversion` which is a `binary(8)` value and it has **nothing** to do with date and times.